# Why can't I define the following CoFixpoint?

Tags: type-inference, coq, coinduction

I am using:

```
$ coqtop -v
The Coq Proof Assistant, version 8.4pl5 (February 2015)
compiled on Feb 06 2015 17:44:41 with OCaml 4.02.1
```

I defined the following `CoInductive` type, `stream`:

```
$ coqtop
Welcome to Coq 8.4pl5 (February 2015)

Coq < CoInductive stream (A : Type) : Type := 
Coq < | Cons : A -> stream A -> stream A.
stream is defined

Coq < Check stream.
stream
     : Type -> Type

Coq < Check Cons.
Cons
     : forall A : Type, A -> stream A -> stream A
```

Then, I tried to define the following `CoFixpoint` definition, `zeros`:

```
Coq < CoFixpoint zeros : stream nat := Cons 0 zeros.
```

However, I got the following error instead:

```
Toplevel input, characters 38-39:
> CoFixpoint zeros : stream nat := Cons 0 zeros.
>                                       ^
Error: In environment
zeros : stream nat
The term "0" has type "nat" while it is expected to have type 
"Type".
```

I figured out that I have to explicitly instantiate the variable `A`:

```
Coq < CoFixpoint zeros : stream nat := Cons nat 0 zeros.
zeros is corecursively defined
```

Why doesn't the Coq infer the type of `A` by itself? How do I make it infer the type of `A`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to declare `A` as implicit to ask Coq to infer it for you. There are a few ways of doing it:

1. Add the following declaration to your file: `Set Implicit Arguments.`. This will cause Coq to turn on automatic inference for arguments such as `A` for `Cons`, allowing you to write `Cons 0 zeros`.
2. Turn on implicit arguments just for `Cons`, without affecting the rest of the file:

   ```
   Arguments Cons {A} _ _.
   ```

   This declaration marks `A` as implicit and leaves the other two arguments as explicit.
3. Mark `A` as implicit in the definition of `stream`:

   ```
   CoInductive stream {A : Type} : Type := 
   | Cons : A -> stream A -> stream A.
   ```

   I personally do not recommend doing this, however, as it will mark `A` as implicit for `stream` as well.

You can find more information about implicit arguments in the [reference manual](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/Reference-Manual004.html#sec100)

Comment: Side note: items 2. and 3. declare `A` as a [maximally-inserted](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/Reference-Manual004.html#Implicit%20Arguments) argument. Implicit arguments inferred with the `Set Implicit Arguments` directive are not declared to be insertable maximally. So, when applicable, one might want to add `Set Maximal Implicit Insertion.`.